# Eclipse not recognizing CygWin gcc

Tags: c++, eclipse, gcc, android-ndk, cygwin

I am trying to build an Android NDK project.

Eclipse says:
[image]

I installed NDK, CygWin (including gcc, g++) correctly I guess. I also added the bin folder to my PATH variable. So when I am opening a command prompt I get following:

[image]

which in my opinion tells me that everything is installed correctly.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I ended up in using Android Studio, which was working immediately

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse is able to overrides default system path. Check out your project and workspace preferences for fault in the path.